# Why PHP foreach loop returns the same value multiple times?

Tags: php, foreach, html-table

I am trying the following PHP code but, I didn't get what I expect. I want to display mark of students from mark table on HTML table. Mark table in database have id r_no, mark, weight, grade_id, subject_id, and exam term (term) attributes. I tried to display array of these mark on HTML table by using foreach loop. But it returns the some values multiple times.

I tried the following code

```
include('config.php');// database connection
?>

 <!--Table to show mark of students -->       
<table table border="1" width="50%" >
    <thead>
        <tr align ="center">
            <th rowspan ="2">Role Number</th> 
            <th align ="center" Colspan ="3">Continuous Assessment</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
                 <!-- queries to select distinct weight from `mark` table based 
                 on the subject, grade, and term of assessment. I want to 
                 retrieve weight of subject_id = 1, grade_id = 1, and term of 
                 assessment is from term 1 to term 3  -->
    <?php
    
        $sql="select DISTINCT weight as a from mark WHERE subject_id=1 and grade_id = 1 and term=1;";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        $count = 0;
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while($weight=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $count++;
                global $a;
                $a = $weight['a'];
                ?>
    <?php 
            } 
        }
                    
        else {
           $a = 0;
                    }
                ?>
    <?php
        $sql="select DISTINCT weight as b from mark WHERE subject_id=1 and grade_id = 1 and term=2;";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        $count = 0;
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while($weight=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $count++;
                global $b;
                $b = $weight['b']
                ?> 
    <?php 
            } 
        }
                    
                    else {
                        $b = 0;
                    }
                ?>
    <?php
        $sql="select DISTINCT weight as c from mark WHERE subject_id=1 and grade_id = 1 and term=3;";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        $count = 0;
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while($weight=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $count++;
                global $c;
                $c = $weight['c']
                ?> 
    <?php 
            } 
        }
                    else {
                        $c = 0;
                    }
                ?>
    
        <tr>
            <th align ="center"><?php echo $a."".'%'; ?></th>
            <th align ="center"><?php echo $b."".'%'; ?></th>
            <th align ="center"><?php echo $c."".'%'; ?></th>
            <th align ="center"><?php echo $a + $b + $c."".'%'; ?></th>
        </tr>
    <!-- upto this step it works correctly the problem start bellow this step -->
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php  
    # queries to retrieve marks that each student achieve from each term of assessment 
    #query to retrieve role number of students
        $r_no = "select mark.r_no as aa from mark WHERE mark.grade_id=1 AND mark.subject_id=1  AND mark.term=1;";
            $result=mysqli_query($conn,$r_no);
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    $r_number[] = array('r_num' => $row['aa']);       
            }?> 

    <?php  
    # query to retrieve term 1 assessment
        $mark_term1 = "select mark.mark as bb from mark WHERE mark.grade_id=1 AND mark.subject_id=1  AND mark.term=1;";
            $result=mysqli_query($conn,$mark_term1);
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $term1[] = array('t1' => $row['bb']);       
        }?> 

    <?php  
    # query to retrieve term 2 assessment
        $mark_term2 = "select mark.mark as cc from mark WHERE mark.grade_id=1 AND mark.subject_id=1  AND mark.term=2;";
            $result=mysqli_query($conn,$mark_term2);
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $term2[] = array('t2' => $row['cc']);       
        }?>

    <?php  
    # query to retrieve term 3 assessment 
        $mark_term3 = "select mark.mark as dd from mark WHERE mark.grade_id=1 AND mark.subject_id=1  AND mark.term=3;";
            $result=mysqli_query($conn,$mark_term3);
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $term3[] = array('t3' => $row['dd']);       
        }?>
        <!-- this is were i get stucked it repeats each queries several times -->
      <?php foreach ($r_number as $rno): ?>
        <?php foreach ($term1 as $tr1): ?>
            <?php foreach ($term2 as $tr2): ?>
                <?php foreach ($term3 as $tr3): ?>
                    
        <tr>   
            <td><?php echo $rno['r_num']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $tr1['t1']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $tr2['t2']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $tr3['t3']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $tr1['t1'] + $tr2['t2'] + $tr3['t3']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Excepting the following result.
[image: excepted output showed on excel sheet]

Instead, the following is what my code displays.
[image: code output]

my mark table source is as follows

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 5.1.1
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Mar 05, 2023 at 07:17 AM
-- Server version: 10.4.20-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 8.0.8

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `student`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `mark`
--

CREATE TABLE `mark` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `r_no` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `mark` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `weight` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `grade_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subject_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `term` int(15) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Dumping data for table `mark`
--

INSERT INTO `mark` (`id`, `r_no`, `mark`, `weight`, `grade_id`, `subject_id`, `term`) VALUES
(1, 'mg1', 9, 10, 1, 1, 1),
(2, 'mg2', 6, 10, 1, 1, 1),
(3, 'mg3', 7, 10, 1, 1, 1),
(4, 'mg4', 9, 10, 2, 1, 1),
(5, 'mg5', 5, 10, 2, 1, 1),
(6, 'mg6', 8, 10, 2, 1, 1),
(7, 'mg1', 5, 9, 1, 2, 1),
(8, 'mg2', 7, 9, 1, 2, 1),
(9, 'mg3', 6, 9, 1, 2, 1),
(10, 'mg4', 5, 9, 2, 2, 1),
(11, 'mg5', 5, 9, 2, 2, 1),
(12, 'mg6', 6, 9, 2, 2, 1),
(13, 'mg1', 8, 8, 1, 3, 1),
(14, 'mg2', 7, 8, 1, 3, 1),
(15, 'mg3', 5, 8, 1, 3, 1),
(16, 'mg4', 5, 8, 2, 3, 1),
(17, 'mg5', 6, 8, 2, 3, 1),
(18, 'mg6', 4, 8, 2, 3, 1),
(19, 'mg1', 8, 12, 1, 1, 2),
(20, 'mg2', 4, 12, 1, 1, 2),
(21, 'mg3', 7, 12, 1, 1, 2),
(22, 'mg4', 9, 12, 2, 1, 2),
(23, 'mg5', 5, 12, 2, 1, 2),
(24, 'mg6', 8, 12, 2, 1, 2),
(25, 'mg1', 5, 5, 1, 2, 2),
(26, 'mg2', 4, 5, 1, 2, 2),
(27, 'mg3', 3, 5, 1, 2, 2),
(28, 'mg4', 4, 5, 2, 2, 2),
(29, 'mg5', 4, 5, 2, 2, 2),
(30, 'mg6', 3, 5, 2, 2, 2),
(31, 'mg1', 18, 20, 1, 3, 2),
(32, 'mg2', 20, 20, 1, 3, 2),
(33, 'mg3', 13, 20, 1, 3, 2),
(34, 'mg4', 16, 20, 2, 3, 2),
(35, 'mg5', 19, 20, 2, 3, 2),
(36, 'mg6', 18, 20, 2, 3, 2),
(37, 'mg1', 12, 18, 1, 1, 3),
(38, 'mg2', 15, 18, 1, 1, 3),
(39, 'mg3', 17, 18, 1, 1, 3),
(40, 'mg4', 12, 18, 2, 1, 3),
(41, 'mg5', 18, 18, 2, 1, 3),
(42, 'mg6', 12, 18, 2, 1, 3),
(43, 'mg1', 13, 14, 1, 2, 3),
(44, 'mg2', 14, 14, 1, 2, 3),
(45, 'mg3', 14, 14, 1, 2, 3),
(46, 'mg4', 13, 14, 2, 2, 3),
(47, 'mg5', 10, 14, 2, 2, 3),
(48, 'mg6', 11, 14, 2, 2, 3),
(49, 'mg1', 18, 18, 1, 3, 3),
(50, 'mg2', 11, 18, 1, 3, 3),
(51, 'mg3', 13, 18, 1, 3, 3),
(52, 'mg4', 16, 18, 2, 3, 3),
(53, 'mg5', 12, 18, 2, 3, 3),
(54, 'mg6', 18, 18, 2, 3, 3);

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `mark`
--
ALTER TABLE `mark`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `mark`
--
ALTER TABLE `mark`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=55;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to see how you can improve your question.

Comment: It's very difficult to predict the output of a sql query without seeing at least some sample source data. Have you tested each of these many queries independently to see if you get the expected results, before integrating into php? If not, that should be your first debugging step

Comment: @ADyson i add source data for table `mark`please help.

Answer (score 0):

You are mapping all your role numbers with all your term1s, term2s and term3s, independently of whether they are related. Let's first see your queries:

- for role numbers is: `select mark.r_no as aa from mark WHERE mark.grade_id=1 AND mark.subject_id=1  AND mark.term=1;`
- query for term1 is: `select mark.mark as bb from mark WHERE mark.grade_id=1 AND mark.subject_id=1  AND mark.term=1;`
- query for term2 is: `select mark.mark as bb from mark WHERE mark.grade_id=1 AND mark.subject_id=1  AND mark.term=2;`
- query for term3 is: `select mark.mark as bb from mark WHERE mark.grade_id=1 AND mark.subject_id=1  AND mark.term=3;`

Let's unify all these queries into the exact query you need that will yield a single row for each role number along with term1, term2 and term3:

```
select mark1.r_no, mark1.mark as mark_1, mark2.mark as mark_2, mark3.mark as mark_3
from mark mark1
join mark mark2
on mark1.grade_id = mark2.grade_id and mark1.subject_id = mark2.subject_id
join mark mark3
on mark1.grade_id = mark3.grade_id and mark1.subject_id = mark3.subject_id
where mark1.term = 1 and mark2.term = 2 and mark3.term = 3
```

If you have duplicates in your database, then you can append a `group by mark1.r_no, mark2.r_no and mark3.r_no` and adjust your `select` clause accordingly.

If sometimes `mark2` or `mark3` may be missing, then you can use `left join` instead.

Yet, this idea allows you to do a single `foreach` and you can rest assured that each of your rows in the result set you have an `r_no` representing the role number, `mark_1`, `mark_2`, `mark_3` representing the corresponding marks.